# How to ensure first keys in all containers are unique in whole stack

Tags: java, stack

I have a two command "add" and "undo". With "add" operation, more than one, including one, pair can be sent to the program. On the other hand, with "undo" operation, last sent data should be given back. To implement this functionality, I have thought;

I should have these elements of data structure;

```
|      |      HashMap<String, String> : It is used for storing data
|      |       
|      |     
|      |
--------
 Stack : It seems best to "undo" and "add" operations.
```

At some point, I should, in practice, have below stack;

```
|                                  |
|                                  |    
| ________________________________ |
| | (filename5, date1)           | |  third HashMap type container 
| | (filename6, date5)           | |  holding three items
| | (filename7, date9)           | |
| |______________________________| |
|                                  |    
| ________________________________ |  second HashMap type container 
| | (filename3, date2)           | |  holding one item
| |______________________________| |
|                                  |    
| ________________________________ |  first HashMap type container 
| | (filename1, date1)           | |  holding two items
| | (filename2, date2)           | |
| |______________________________| |
|----------------------------------|
```

My question is "How can I ensure first keys in all containers are **unique** in the **whole stack**?"

If it is not possible with above data structures, what should I use as a data structure to implement mentioned wish?

Comment: what is what you are trying to avoid. Having two `filename1`?

Comment: @SJuan76 I am trying to avoid dublicate two entries such as filename in the stack. For filename case, I donot want let user to choose same filename twice. If I let, the whole stack can be filled with, e.g., (filename1, date1), (filename2, date3), (filename1, date1), (filename2, date3) ...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keeping two structures: `Stack<String>` and check, whether it contains or not `filename_x`, and second structure - your hashmap `HashMap<String, String>`?

UPD: In other words, you do not need to hold theese maps inside stack as its elements.

Comment: Think If user had sent five items at once, then pressed "undo" button. How can I give back last five items? Continue, user pressed again in "undo" button, this time I should sent three items back because they all added at once. ...

Answer (score 0):

It is solved with three `Java Stack`, and own stack implementation to make `push` and `pop` operations synhronized. Implementation is ;

```
class OwnStack{
  private final Stack<String> file = new Stack<String>()
  private final Stack<String> date = new Stack<String>()
  private final Stack<String> numberOfElementsPushedAtTheSamTime 
          = new Stack<String>()

  public void push(String []files, String []date{
     /*       Algorithm
      *  Iterate over files
      *     if file is in stack
      *        donot push anything to stack
      *     else
      *        push file to stack
      *        push category to stack
      *  push number of entries pushed at the same time to stack (files.length())
      */
  }

  public void pop(){
     /*  
      *         Algorithm
      *  If size is zero in file stack
      *      do nothing
      *  else
      *      get top number from numberOfElementsPushedAtTheSamTime stack
      *      iterate over stacks returned number times
      *          pop files stack
      *          pop date stack
      */
     // I donot need return values
  }
}
```